# Eclipse sees this code as error, but it compiles fine in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-data

I have a project using spring framework, and I am trying to create a CrudController, and Eclipse is pointing out that I have an error in my code, however the code compiles fine.

It fails on UserController.java::5 -

`Bound mismatch: The type UserService is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <S extends Service<M,CrudRepository<M,Long>>> of the type CrudController<M,S>`

Here is the code:

UserController.java (Where error occurs)

```
package app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class UserController extends CrudController<User, UserService>{

  @Autowired
  @Override
  public void setService(UserService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

}
```

CrudController.java

```
package app;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

public abstract class CrudController<M extends Model, S extends Service<M, CrudRepository<M,Long>>> {
  S service;
  public abstract void setService(S service);
  public @ResponseBody Iterable<M> getJson() {
    return service.getAll();
  }
}
```

Model.java

```
package app;

public class Model {

}
```

Service.java

```
package app;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public abstract class Service <M extends Model, R extends CrudRepository<M, Long>> {
  R repo;
  public abstract void setRepo(R repo);
  public Iterable<M> getAll() {
    return repo.findAll(); 
  }
}
```

User.java

```
package app;

public class User extends Model {

}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package app;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

UserService.java

```
package app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class UserService extends Service<User, UserRepository> {

  @Autowired
  @Override
  public void setRepo(UserRepository repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code in your question itself rather than only through a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CrudController` is expecting a subclass of `Service` with `CrudRepository`,

```
public abstract class CrudController<M extends Model, 
  S extends Service<M, CrudRepository<M,Long>>> { ..
```

But you are giving it a subclass of `Service` with subclass of `CrudRepository`.

You can change the CrudController signature ...

```
/* takes any CrudRepository */
public abstract class CrudController<M extends Model, 
  S extends Service<M, ? extends CrudRepository<M,Long>>> { ..
```

or

```
/* takes any CrudRepository */
public abstract class CrudController<M extends Model, 
  R extends CrudRepository<M, Long>, S extends Service<M,R>> { ..

/* you'll have to be explicit in UserController with this signature */
public class UserController extends CrudController<User, UserRepository, UserService>{
```